# Saving formatted code

Tags: export, formatting, code

I am writing some ODE notes with lots of pictures generated using Mathematica, and I'd like to include the code used to generate them.

Currently I have a notebook where all the pictures are generated. I have a `doImage` function that gets a filename, and a graphic object and exports it — nothing fancy at all.

```
doImage["sine-function",
  Plot[
    Sin[t], 
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}
    ]
]
```

Is there a way to have `doImage` also save the *code* it gets in the second argument? A plaintext rendition, say (it'd eventually get included in a LaTeX file, maybe after being run through pygments for prettyfication) I think one could make the function hold its arguments unevaluated and save them, *but* ideally the saved code would also keep the formatting! At least, the indentation, say.

I don't really understand why, so let me be explicit: what I am asking is how to get the function all above to produce a textfile whose contexts are

```
Plot[
  Sin[t], 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}
  ]
```

Since I know how to save a string to a textfile, I would be equally please, of course, with learning how to produce a *string* which when serialized into a textfile would produce that.

---

FWIW, one *can* get an actual plaintext rendtion of a cell of code in a string with its original indentation — or a close approximation thereof —  by saying something like

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[CellStyle -> {"Input"}], All, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute[SelectedNotebook[], "CopySpecial", "InputText"];
str = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]]
```

It even gets fractions, exponents and roots correct.
The lines are wrapped (with correct indentation), but it'd be nice to control at what column, though.

Comment: Oh, wait. I read "a plaintext rendition" and thought that's what you wanted. Did you already achieve what my answer provides, and now you want to add the UI formatting on top of that?

Comment: @lericr, I actually need plain text (I want it to be copy/pastable, for example)

Comment: Where do you want it to be saved???

Comment: If I learn how to turn the code into a string then I can save it in the correct place, that's not really the problem.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: Then I do not understand why you are asking "how to save code" (which has vague meaning in what you mean by saving) instead of "how to convert code into string".

Comment: As a mathematician, I am used to reducing problems to simpler problems. As I know how to write a string to a file, doing what I want to do is reduced to generating the string that should end up in the file. I honestly do not understand why this is so difficult to understand, really!

Comment: One way to get *almost* the indentation is to abandon the idea of getting the code as an argument, ok, put it in a cell by itself, get the cell `c` form the notebook and say `ToString@DisplayForm@NotebookRead@c[[1,1]]`, but sadly `ToString` does not do anything with the `\[IndentingNewLine]` thingies. so only explicit indentation is in the resulting string.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are falling squarely for the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) fallacy: you think you figured out a partial solution to your problem and you are seeking help with your *solution* (generate a string from code), rather than with your actual *problem* (save and export code in plain text), without realizing that a better potential pathway may exist. That is the source of the frustration in some comments.

Comment: "Generating a string from code" and "saving and that sporting code in plain text" are, for my purpose, equivalent, provided the formatting is kept, in that if I can solve one I can solve the other. I have no idea in what what you make a difference between "a string" and "plain text".

Comment: My problem is extremely simple: I have code in a MMA notebook, and I have a latex document into which I want to include parts of the code that appears in the notebook, formatted as closely as possible as it is there (keeping the indentation already would we great), just as I include python code in that same document.

Comment: The better potential pathways seem to be, so far, storing the unformatted code in a comment in a PNG file, put the code and the graph in a Column and export that (as a graphics?), store the actual cell in the notebook is a compressed string which when treated appropriately inside MMA will product the exact same cell I had.

Comment: Each of those proposals was actually useful, in that I learned something from each, surely. For example, I did not know of  `CodeFormat[ToString[Hold[expr]]]`, which is nice and which, amusingly, requires one to turn the code into a string, as does the comment in the PNG.

Comment: Can anyne explain exactly what details or clarity is missing from this question? i **honestly** cannot understand this.

Answer (score 4):

You can save the code in the comments of the file. I use [`ExportByteArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportByteArray.html) and [`ImportByteArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportByteArray.html) to demonstrate but you can convert this to [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html).

```
ClearAll[doImageCode];
SetAttributes[doImageCode, HoldFirst]
doImageCode[expr_, filename_, imageformat_ : "PNG"] :=
 ExportByteArray[ReleaseHold[expr], 
  imageformat, {"Comments" -> {"WLCode" -> ToString[Hold[expr]]}}]
```

Then

```
ba1 = doImageCode[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2  Pi}], "test"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`Import` image with

```
ImportByteArray[ba1, "PNG"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`Import` code with

```
ImportByteArray[ba1, {"PNG", "Comments", "WLCode"}]
```

> ```
> "Hold[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]"
> ```

You can then use [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) to access the code.  Also, other software should be able to access this meta data as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this is interesting, notice that I actually want a plain text, separate file. There is really not a lot of point in saving the code inside the image and then extracting the code from the image when I can save the code in a text file directly.

Comment: Also, this will lose all formatting in the code.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You can simply export the `Hold[expr]` to a txt file in your code.  I originally experimented with [`CodeFormat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CodeFormatter/ref/CodeFormat.html) (e.g. `CodeFormat[ToString[Hold[expr]]]` ) but I could not get it to give sensible formatting.  You can try with your txt export.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The key is to use the Hold* attributes. I'll demonstrate with HoldRest.

```
SetAttributes[doImage, HoldRest];
doImage[title_, expression_] := Column[{title, ToString[Unevaluated[expression]], expression}];

doImage["sine-function", Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2  Pi}]]
```

[image]

Comment: (This does something weird sometimes, btw. The image https://i.stack.imgur.com/of4Hw.png is the output cell, saved as a PNG, of the result of calling your function on some code. The random letters are numerators/denominators of fractions that appear in the code generating the image)

Comment: I guess that code was serialized into three lines, which the frontend wrapped :-/

Comment: That's how `ToString` handles fractions. You could process the code in some other way, maybe `InputForm`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first cell group (code of which is to be saved as a string that preserve exact formatting of original cell):

[image]

Code of the input cell of the first cell group:

```
Plot[
     Sin[t],
     {t, 0, 2 Pi}
     ]

2^3 + 5^7 +
 8
```

Code of the second input cell (when executed it exports previous group cell as image and also saves the code of the first input cell into variable `code` as compressed string.

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellGroup];

Export["C:\\CellGroup.png", 
 Notebook[{DeleteCases[NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
    CellLabel -> _, \[Infinity]]}], "PNG"]

code = Compress@
  ToString[DeleteCases[NotebookRead[SelectedCells[][[1]]], 
    CellLabel -> _], InputForm]
```

---

```
"C:\\CellGroup.png"

"1:eJx1UMtugzAQTP+E+tjSyi4stnuI1BJVyi0KufGQSIQSJAIoATUS4uP6Z/\
FaNRQ18WF3PDszfjxuq3Xw8zCb+VlRhJ/VZZE2aditq2+\
Fx05WRdUQ2yIhligqsVlqqf5PG+TlINWmmPSxavZ9L+n+brRJq6lBw+\
xNu7GschWrg3sDpuHm3Oj9y/lwJvjGrXVwguVX+\
qxw0NbZ6bw75XWDKgI458SMxzgizB2WZd3iA/BD/\
UNa7rNNfszO1svc6pxXyTxJPQCQHCRjT4m0R5pTCkAFd7nmB5pRTzLhuqDofuQFeEy6Ugi\
k4yusHnd/"
```

Then you can copy the compressed string or use variable `code` to print a cell of exactly the same formatting as you see in the notebook.

```
CellPrint@ToExpression@Uncompress@code
```

which will produce this:

[image]

Comment: This is certainly useful, as it very good way to embed the code in a usable way, thanks! But it does not result into something I can include in a figure in a latex document in a usable way.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: Copying code as plaintext from some latex file and pasting it into Mathematica can never fully preserve the original Mathematica formatting.

Comment: There are degrees of loss. From ToString to the thing with the clipboard  I added to the question there is a difference, say, and it is clear that no plaintext rendition will retain all the format, as the format includes colors, special characters, some 2D expressions, proportional spacing, and I guess other things. Your compressed cell approach is on one end of the spectrum, I'd say! But as I said, I found your answer useful.